# Passing argument to instance method to avoid retain cycle?

Tags: ios, swift, automatic-ref-counting

I've recently started profiling one of my iOS app written in `swift` and realized how annoying ARC is compared to other more adopted GC like Mark-And-Sweep.

One of the most prevalent causes for `Strong Reference Cycle` was retaining instance property within a closure that is passed to another object retained, again, by the class.

For example,

```
  class MyClass {
    private let text = "hello world"
    private let anotherClass = AnotherClass()
    init() {
      addText() 
    }
    private func addText() {
      anotherClass.addText { return self.text }
    }
  }
```

Retain cycle like above can be avoided by passing argument to the method instead of accessing `self` directly.

```
class MyClass {
  private let text = "hello world"
  private let anotherClass = AnotherClass()
  init() { 
    addText(text)
  }
  private func addText(text:String) {
    anotherClass.addText { return text }
  }
}
```

Is the second approach considered a good practice?

FYI, I'm aware that retain cycle like above can be broken using capture list. I'm just curious as to patterns that are more resilient to memory leaks.

Comment: @Daij-Djan yes it is. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting#Use_in_garbage_collection

Comment: stil no ;) reference counting can be used by GC but arc isn't a GC. The compiler inserts retain and release calls for you thats all

Comment: please don't add objective-c tags to swift related questions

Comment: since you answered with a wikipedia link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_Reference_Counting

Comment: @Jasper This isn't swift-related question but ARC in general, which includes Objective-C. swift was used for an illustration purpose only

Comment: @Daij-Djan you are right. reference counting is a form of GC but ARC isn't. :]

Comment: the question is good though .. and I don't know the answer either -- that why I had to nitpick ;)

Answer (score 0):

Since the property `let text ...` is a constant, I think that the second approach is fine and can be considered a best practice.

But if you use the same approach with a `var text ...` property, then the behaviour changes:

- in the first approach an execution of the closure will use the **current** value of `text`,
- while in the second approach an execution of the closure will always use the **original** value of `text`.